# Remove previously recognized words from speech recognition api results

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

In using the Javascript Speech Recognition API I am discovering that all my previous statements are being displayed along with the newest ones, is there a way I can have all the previous ones clear out after a new phrase has been recognized?

This is the basic way I'm working with the speech recognition.

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true; 
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.start();
recognition.onresult = function(event){ 
    console.log(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use https://github.com/Manohar-Gunturu/rs.speech.js library.

```
speechRs.rec_start('en-IN',function(final_transcript,interim_transcript){
      console.log(final_transcript,interim_transcript);
      // final_transcript gives complete transcript from the beginning 
      // interim_transcript return the transcript the user has spoken 
      // from last break he took
});
```

Check the demo here https://jsfiddle.net/r6ftm7oq/

Answer (score -1):

I think that You are appending the results. You should not append the results. you should over write the results. let say in java

```
 @Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG+">"+ "onResults");
    ArrayList<String> matches = results
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    String text = "";
    for (String result : matches)
        text += result + "\n";
    if(text.contains(my key word list here)){
       //you can skip this if part

    }
```

I hope this gives you idea what are you doing wrong. (supposing that you have arraylist of results)

Comment: I'm using javascript not java

Comment: I provided you a sample @jordan. I supposed you can convert it into a your language and according to your need

Comment: i would suggest you to save the result in string variable in this function

recognition.onresult = function(event){ 
    console.log(event);
 //like here and try log out that variable 

}